# StreamWriter writing a text file's content incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

I am using the `StreamWriter` class to write some text to a newly created text file, but the output is always weirdly wrong, this is my code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("newtextfile.txt", false, Encoding.Unicode);
for (int d = 0; d < count; d++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(d + '＾' + str1[d] + '＾' + str2[d] + '＾' + str3[d]);
}
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

the output goes like this(this is the start of the file):

```
65342STR1＾STR2＾STR3
65343STR1＾STR2＾STR3
```

...etc

I have no idea why is the `WriteLine` skipping the `d + '＾'` and writing that random number.

Comment: Why this question was downvoted? come on

Comment: They always downvote my questions, because in SO, you gotta start somewhere, but that somewhere must always be advanced.

Comment: Cheer up man , it happens sometimes :-). +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `"`:

```
sw.WriteLine(d + "＾" + str1[d] + "＾" + str2[d] + "＾" + str3[d]);
```

With expressions like

```
int d = 0;
var t = d + '＾'; // int + char
```

type of `t` is `int`, not `string`.

---

In your case, `65342` (`== 0xFF3E`) appears because it is a Unicode for this special `^`-like character (fullwidth circumflex accent).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i didn't have any idea why it was outputing like this, but now it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

It is adding the integer value of the char literal '^' to d, so if `d=123` then `d + '^' = 217`. Use string literals instead.

```
sw.WriteLine(d + "＾" + str1[d] + "＾" + str2[d] + "＾" + str3[d]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this expression:

```
d + '＾'
```

doesn't involve any strings. It's trying to add an `int` and a `char`, which it does by promoting the `char` to `int` (which will have a value of 65342, because that's the UTF-16 code unit for `'＾'`), and then performing normal numeric addition. The result (an `int`) is then being converted to a string due to the subsequent `+` operator with `str1[d]` as its right-hand operand.

You *could* use string literals instead:

```
d + "＾" + ...
```

but I would personally use formatting instead:

```
sw.WriteLine("{0}＾{1}＾{2}＾{3}", d, str1[d], str2[d], str3[d]);
```

That's simpler to read, in my view.

Comment: @AlexD: Yes, that would make sense given the values we we're seeing. Thanks, will fix.